# Replace part of string of elements of lists in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

**Set-up**

I have a dictionary where each key contains a list of at least one string element.

Here is a part of the dictionary,

```
d = {
  'Bergen-Enkheim': ['Bergen-Enkheim'],
  'Bornheim/Ostend': ['Ostend,\xa0Bornheim'],
  'Harheim': ['Harheim'],
  'Innenstadt I': ['Altstadt,\xa0Bahnhofsviertel,\xa0Gallus,'
                   '\xa0Gutleutviertel,\xa0Innenstadt']
}
```

---

**Problem**

Most of the elements start with `\xa0` which I want to replace with a white space.

I tried the following loop,

```
for key in d:
   for x in d[key]:
       x = x.replace('\xa0', ' ')
```

but `d` stays the same. How do I replace the unwanted characters with a white space?

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a classic iteration over the values:

```
for values in d.values():
    values[:] = [x.replace('\xa0', ' ') for x in values]
```

Each list is modified in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so `x.replace(...)` produces a new string rather than changing the existing string in the dictionary list. Then, the statement `x = ...` updates `x` to be a name for the new string. In short, you have to change the entry in the dictionary list explicitly.

```
for key in d2:
   for i, x in enumerate(d2[key]):
       d2[key][i] = x.replace('\xa0', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over keys and then update values

```
for key in d:
    d[key] = [s.replace('\xa0', '') for s in d[key]]
```